# How to create a training example from an RGB image in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision, face-recognition

I have RGB face images of size 60x60. They are matrices of size
60x60x3 in Matlab.

I need to apply some algorithms to these data. But first I need
to create training examples for the images. Given one image of size
60x60x3 I will need to create a vector of size 1x10800. I am not sure,
should I interleave the R, G and B values for the pixels, should I go
column by column or row by row?

Thanks

Comment: Unless your learning algorithm involves knowledge of physical proximity between pixels, it doesn't matter either way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, it does not matter. For instance, SVM classifier or neural network perceptron are invariant to any permutations of the input.
If your image is `im`, just use `im(:)` to transform it into a column.